# Store document in local storage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I want to store document(.pdf,.txt,.etc) in localstorage using javascript. I used one file input to accept document in html. But it gives me fake path like 'c:/fake/abc.pdf'. Please help me to solve my problem.
Thanks.

Comment: There are two missing parts: **1)** reading files in HTML5 (search for it) **2)** put a big file in a very small storage space (search another design)

Comment: Please, provide [SSCCE of what you had done](http://sscce.org/)

Answer (score 0):

You can access files using HTML5 files API. Read this:[link](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/)
In localstorage you can store only strings, so you can store file contents.
**EDIT**: storing file contents in localstorage is **not good** idea, because max localstorage size per origin is 10 MB.

Comment: *"you can store only strings, so you can store file contents."* ?

Comment: For example  .txt file contents

Comment: Do you have an idea of the capacity of localStorage ?

Comment: Thanks. Added warning in answer